# What is monograph and digraph in keyboard optimization problem?

Tags: terminology, optimization

I have been working on Bangla keyboard optimization. I've taken [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwijraHp8cLJAhWGCI4KHQ3RDwYQFggtMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhal.archives-ouvertes.fr%2Fhal-00748742%2Fdocument&usg=AFQjCNGifyiiQnL2iAtFn9S7dqVDQ8qvHQ&sig2=iFRUOAmR_6HPkuvpquzRhw&bvm=bv.108538919,d.c2E) paper as a reference. In this paper they have introduce two terms monograph and digraph. But it is not clear how they have calculate these two things. In this paper it is written -

> A monograph is an isolated key which is struck in the process of typing a text. A digraph is a sequence of two consecutive keys hit in the process of typing a text. This idea allows the distinction between rules that concern the absolute position of a given key and the relative position of two consecutive keys.

What I am assuming that digraph is those two consecutive character that are used often in any language word. Like in English language ph, qu etc. But I can not understand what is monograph.

Therefore I would need a clear explanation about monograph and digraph and what is the method to calculate these in respect to keyboard optimization problem.

Comment: These terms *probably* are older than the problem's treatment in CS.

Answer (score 1):

The article uses `monograph` to refer to a single key, say "e", in a position on the keyboard. In the interest of efficiency, you'd want the frequently-used letters to be in locations where a model typist would have to expend the least motion to strike. A `digraph`, on the other hand, would be two keys which would be struck in sequence, like the "in" which I typed a few characters ago. In this case, we would be looking for a keyboard layout which minimized the effort depending not just on the absolute positions of the characters, but on the relative positions of the pairs.

Comment: is digraph means only relative position of two character or there are specific type of character set like bl, br, ch etc ? I found [this](http://www.enchantedlearning.com/consonantblends/) site for English digraph.

Comment: @MuztabaHasanat. Not quite. A digraph is just a pair of letters. The reason it was mentioned in the article was because the authors were interested in the relative positions of pairs of letters and a pair of letters is what's known as a digraph.

Answer (score 0):

A monograph is a single letter that was typed at some point.

A digraph is a pair of consecutive letters that were typed one after the other.

For instance, if I type `sock`, the monographs are `s`, `o`, `c`, and `k`; the digraphs are `so`, `oc`, and `ck`.